# Imgur image resize not always working

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

I've done this a few times, usually successfully, but for some reason it doesn't always seem to work.

I edited this one today & as far as I can see, only the first image has successfully linked to a 'medium' image; the other still links to 'large'.

[How can I get full-length 'shadowless' portrait photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/103583/how-can-i-get-full-length-shadowless-product-photography)

Can we tell if this is an error on my part, an imgur issue, or if they have implemented some new structure?

I've been playing with this one troublesome image a while to see if I can see what's going on; even so far as to re-upload it to see if anything changes [it doesn't].
s and b sizes work on it, though, just not m.

Similar questions on Meta SE
[The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/276027)
[Is the continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still temporary, or permanent? ETA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315004/276027)

Comment: Over the past few (several?) months (on other SE sites), I've found the storage on imgur to be, at best, inconsistent wrt. supporting appending `m`, etc., to get a smaller version of the image. In order to get images to show up at appropriate resolutions, I've, generally, had to resort to using a `<img>` tag with explicitly specified `width` and/or `height`.

Comment: At least not an error on your part: [Is the continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still temporary, or permanent? ETA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315004)

Comment: Please don't use `img` to downsize very large images — they still use up people's data.

Comment: @mattdm I stream YouTube constantly and still don’t use even 1gb per month. What do people do to where the difference between a 200kb image and 3mb image is cause for concern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sake of completeness - this is now fixed.

[The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly)

Admin answer -
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327075/276027